# nodeJS Async vs Sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In nodeJS it is a general practice and recommendation to use **async** methods and make callbacks to the next function.

I set up a nodeJS using [expressJS](https://expressjs.com/) for testing purposes and I wrote **sync** and **async** methods. Both methods work and express will answer to all requests without any **perceptible** delay whether using **async** or **sync** methods.

Although I use **async** methods in my project, the articles I read that encourage to use **async** methods did not explain why in deep.
**Sync** methods would avoid a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

So I got curious, why not use **sync** methods since they both work? Would it impact in response time/performance by using one or another?

Comment: It depends on what are you doing asynchronously. If it is a trivial task it will not take much time. But think about a web request, there is no guarantee when the server will respond. It can even keep you on hold (e.g. log polling). And an asynchronous calls blocks your current thread.

Comment: I set up this express server 90% to return JSONs to ajax requests. The data stored in those JSONs are retrieved from the local hard drive and some times from 3rd party servers.

Comment: HDD access takes soem considerable time even though you cannot perceive, not to mention 3rd party server (network) access. Try measuring the time taken and see for yourself. Maybe a single read will not be an issue but if your service is being used by multiple users, then everybody has to wait other requests to complete.

Comment: It's not about perceptible delay in your single requests.  It's about blocking when a server processes many requests from many users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Node runs on a single thread. If you are handling lots of connections, there will be surely more IO-bound tasks than CPU-bound tasks. For example, DB calls.
While you are waiting for a database query result, you can receive more requests, or do other jobs.

The problem starts when you need to do something that is CPU-bound: a task that may take much time. You need to split the task, making a tiny part of it, and then scheduling the rest to a later time until it's finished, or you can delegate it to another server / process, whatever.

If you decide to go sync, the server won't handle any more requests while doing that job. Yes, you will avoid the callback hell, but at the cost of doing one task from start to the end no matter how long it is. If you are trying to handle lots of connections, this won't be good.

A good example of when it is a trouble, are the for loops:

```
for (let x of ['some', 'huge', 'array']) {
  // Do something heavy here, until it's not finished, server won't do
  // anything more than this heavy task
}
```

While "doing something", the server application won't handle any other incoming request. Of course, the problem will be serious when you have a heavier task, and lots of requests.

In a serious Node server, you don't want a synchronous loop, unless it performs better than an asynchronous solution because of X motive. So, you go async with setTimeout, setImmediate, process.nextTick, Promises, etc. And, probably the first approach you take is going with the continuation-passing style, it means, passing callbacks to be executed after the work is done, and probably you will hit the callbacks hell wall.

That's the moment when you go with Promises, or generators, or both:
https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators

This way, you will avoid the callbacks hell, and also get a nicer code (subjective). Also you maybe want to keep an eye on async/await: https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait.

You don't have any notable advantage because you are the only user making requests. Make tests with, say, thousands of connections.

Abrazo.

Comment: So, lets say I set on my express to listen(): `/someLongProcess` and `/regularAsyncResponses`. Could I use **sync** mode in `/someLongProcess` while **async** mode in `/regularAsyncResponses`. Would one "thread" delay the other?

Comment: There are simply no threads. Though you can have child processes, each process will have it's own event loop (see cluster module). What Node really does is ONE thing at a time, if you put some sync for-loop, you will lock the event loop of the process until the for ends.
And yes, if you have a sync operatio, the async operation will have to wait until the sync operations finishes.
If you want to make "more than one operation at the same time" (remember, one thread), you will have to split "heavy" tasks into smaller,  ones, or delegate it to another process.

Comment: @Azevedo No, you cannot do that. A sync call will always block the complete server.

Comment: So, `return` should not be used in nodeJS?

Comment: It can be used, if you don't put a return, it returns undefined.
But when you use callbacks, the return won't affect the program's flow, because before returning, the callback will be called with the results of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

You can put food in the microwave, take a bath in the meantime, and when you finish your bath you can (probably) you take your food out of the microwave and eat it. If the food isn't ready yet, you can do something else until it's ready. That's the async way.

Or, your can put food in the microwave, stare at the microwave until it finishes, eat your food, and then take your bath. That's the sync way.

Comment: note that staring at the microwave while its on might cause cancer. same with sync functions when used unnecessarily in javascript :D

Comment: @noisypixy your explanation wasn't technical. no code provided proving your theory.

Comment: @Azevedo, it isn't technical, nor edible suggestion. In fact, microwave is one of the worstest IDE for it's primary purpose - making food.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the code bellow:

```
server.get('/wait', function(request, response){

    var wait = true;
    while (wait) { // force synchronous delay of 10s
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('answering now');
            response.send('<pre>hello, i am 10s late</pre>');
            wait = false;
        }, 10000);
    }
});

server.get('/now', function(request, response){

    response.send('<pre>hello!</pre>');
});
```

---

Calling **first** http://127.0.0.1/wait **and then** http://127.0.0.1/now:

`/now` is answered right away. One thread **does not** interfere in one another.

---

Calling **first** http://127.0.0.1/wait **and then** http://127.0.0.1/wait:

The second call won't be answered before the 1st call have been answered. One thread **does** interfere in one another.

Comment: Bare in mind Node is single threaded and immitates multi threading by using an Event Driven system.  Callbacks give the illusion of asynchronous behaviour but Node does not run on a threaded model.

Comment: Also note, that the reason you use async methods, is because you are not holding up the event queue - consider an application that has a GUI running and some long running underlying code that runs synchronously.   If you wanted to wait for this work to be done, you're blocking the event queue, preventing any other events from taking place whilst that method executes, this is extremely bad from a UX perspective.

Comment: You may also want to look into promises, that way you can set up a pipeline of how code is supposed to be executed without blocking the event queue.  You simply chain promises together which will run those code blocks asynchronously, but only enter the next code block when the previous promise resolves.

Comment: This is a bad example, as the infinite loop in `/wait` will always cause the complete server to hang forever. There are no threads.

Comment: @Bergi Well then why don't you provide a valid example before voting it down?

Comment: @Azevedo Why don't you fix your example so that I can upvote it instead?

Comment: Fell free to edit it. I'm just a beginner in javascript.